# Adding users to ZKTeco access door using Push SDK

Tags: c#, zkteco

I'm trying  to add users to the Door Access Control Device: "inBio 260"

I'm told I need to use the Push/Pull SDK to do that.

```
public bool AddUser(User u) {
    return axCZKEM1.SSR_SetDeviceData(machineNumber, "user", u + "\r\n", "");
}

class User {
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            "CardNo=" + ID + "\t" +
            "Pin=" + Pin + "\t" +
            "Name=" + Name + "\t" +
            "Password=" + Password + "\t" +
            "StartTime=" + StartTime + "\t" +
            "EndTime=" + EndTime;
    }
}

public bool AddFingerprint(Fingerprint p)
{
    return
        IsPinValid(p.Pin) &&
        p.Template != null &&
        p.Template.Length > 100 &&
        axCZKEM1.SSR_SetDeviceData(machineNumber, "templatev10", p + "\r\n", "");
    }
}

class Fingerprint {
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        int size = Convert.FromBase64String(Template).Length;
        return
            "Size=" + size +
            "\tPin=" + Pin +
            "\tFingerID=" + FingerID +
            "\tValid=1\tTemplate=" + Template +
            "\tEndTag=" + EndTag;
    }
}
```

I use "ZKAccess 3.5" to check and I find the users I added and everything seems fine.
But suddenly the machine will report 0 valid fingerprints. And the doors won't open.
Calling AddFingerprint to restore the lost fingerprint returns a false "true", i.e. nothing was added and the machine still has 0 fingerprints left.

Note: ZKAccess is limited to 2000 users, I added 2600+ users.

Update: ZKAccess has 2654 users in its database, clicking sync to device only restores the 900 users that where added using ZKAccess itself (foul play suspected).

Update: I confused push & pull sdk, they are not the same. PullSDK is free, push SDK is private to ZKTeco

Comment: for getting push sdk supported, you need the ADMS supported device, Does your inbio260 support ADMS?

Comment: Not Sure, it's a remote job, I did not closely examine the device. But I worked with time attendance devices, and if I add a user using the SDK, that's it. The user does not get suddenly deleted. That's what's happening here. Out of nowhere, the machine says there are ZERO users. And trying to add those users back does not work, unless I use ZKAccess by clicking: "Synchronize to device". But that removes everything that was not added using ZKAccess.

Comment: Using SDK is not an illegal job. So, better talk to your vendor who provided ZKAccess and get it fixed. It looks like the software failing to sync with the users in the device, as they are added through another software. But , this is not a bad job to do. You have 3 options (1) Work with ZKAccess software vendor and get it fixed (2) Develop complete software with the SDK available (3) Increase the license count if possible

Comment: There is a web api service is available from cams biometrics for zkteco devices, check if that helps: https://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html

Comment: I don't think this can help, but thanks anyway. The problem is that their software - ZKAccess - is deleting the data because I exceeded the limit set for the free version. I just have to stop using their software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZKAccess3.5 deleted all data because the limit of the free version was exceeded.

EDIT: Just for anyone looking for an answer, Push sdk is a private sdk used only by ZKteco. Pull sdk how ever is free but has no documentation. I wrote a wrapper in C#: [code](https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper)